# Javascript working in Google Chrome Console but not on website

Tags: javascript

I am trying to click a next button in a multi step form, when a certain div is visible.

So far the code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($("#loader").is(":visible")) {
    $(".forward").click();
  }
});
```

JQuery is embedded in the footer and this script works in the console, but not in the actual page.

Could you help me with a possible solution?

Thanks in Advance. :-)

Comment: This only checks for visibility when the page is first loaded. If you want it to take place when the div becomes visible, you need to put the code in a `scroll` event listener.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented it this way now:

$(document).ready(function(){
 
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
 
 if($("#loader").is(":visible")){
 $(".forward").click(); 
          }
 });
 });

It still does not work.

Comment: Try using the [devTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript) to provide a bit more debug information: are there any warnings or exceptions thrown in the console when loading the page? Set [breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript#code-stepping) to see if your code is called when scrolling or at all.

Comment: Got it to work by the following function. Is there a way to use a scroll event listener when nothing is scrolling?

$(document).ready(function(){
 var x = document.getElementById("forward");
 var y = document.getElementById("backward");
 window.addEventListener('click', function() {
 
  if($("#loader").is(":visible")){
   x.style.display = "none";
   y.style.display = "none";
   setTimeout(function(){ 
    $(".forward").click(); 
  }, 2000);
          } 
 })
 });